# Can't start PowerShell but I can start PowerShell x86

Tags: powershell

I can't start PowerShell on my computer, but I can start PowerShell x86 perfectly fine. When I launch PowerShell on my computer, I get this error:

> Attempting to perform the Start operation on the 'Registry' provider failed. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Attempting to perform the Start operation on the 'Alias' provider failed. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Attempting to perform the Start operation on the 'Environment' provider failed. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Attempting to perform the Start operation on the 'Function' provider failed. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Attempting to perform the Start operation on the 'Variable' provider failed. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Cannot find path 'C:\Users\my name' because it does not exist.
> Cannot find path 'C:\Users\my name' because it does not exist.
> Cannot find path 'C:\Users\my name' because it does not exist.

I have no idea why it wouldn't recognize the user path and I can't find anything online. From what I understand the x86 version is the 32 bit version and the normal one is the 64 bit one but I am running it on a 64 bit processor so I don't understand why the 32 bit version works and the 64 bit version doesn't. My PowerShell version is 5.1.19041.3031

I have scoured all over the internet and cant find any solutions to this. Any help would be very appreciate

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with your 64-bit .NET Framework installation, which PowerShell relies on.

Comment: As a workaround you may try to install the actively developed [PowerShell (Core) 7.3.5](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.3.5). That depends on .NET framework as well, but is able to use a more recent .NET version.

Comment: Power shell uses the environmental PSMODULEPATH which may have an error.  See if you can start powershell through full path name : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Comment: @jdweng, this question is about the fundamental inability to even launch PowerShell; the `PSModulePath` environment variable has nothing to do with this (it is only used by a successfully launched PowerShell session to locate PowerShell modules). Also, the symptom suggests that `powershell.exe` _can_ be located - but then fails on startup - so I wouldn't expect using the full path to make a difference.

Comment: @mklement0 : How can you launch PS if PSModulePath is corrupted.

Comment: @jdweng: By simply invoking `powershell.exe`. The value of `PSModulePath` doesn't matter with respect to being able to launch _PowerShell itself_. You can verify this by launching the following from a `cmd.exe` session:  First, submit `set PSModulePath=gobbledybook`. Then, invoke `powershell.exe`

Comment: @jdweng, unless you see a flaw in my previous comment, please consider deleting your previous comments and feel free to flag my responses as "It's no longer needed". Perhaps more importantly, please don't post future comments about `PSModulePath` on questions _they do not apply to_.

Comment: @penguinjuice311, are you still having problems?  The problem you are describing may be fixable by something as simple as restarting the computer or running PowerShell as an Administrator, or may requiring something more drastic such as repairing Windows.  In all likelihood, it's probably something in between such as installing all Windows and Microsoft updates, or, if we can figure out the problematic component, perhaps repairing or reinstalling it.

Comment: @darin yeah sorry i fixed it, it turns out mklement0 was right and i had to repair windows bc i accidentally deleted some .NET 4 files